# How to make TD to avoid using single amp retrieve?

Tags: sql, performance, query-optimization, teradata, spool

I have such query:

```
select * from view -- not very simple logic
where report_date between date'2016-01-01' and date'2016-12-31';
```

Then I take big time interval:

TD picks such plan:

```
3) We do an all-AMPs RETRIEVE step from Spool 25 (Last Use) by way of
     an all-rows scan with a condition of ("(REPORT_DT >= DATE
     '2016-01-01') AND (REPORT_DT <= DATE '2016-12-31')") into Spool 36
     (all_amps) (compressed columns allowed) fanned out into 3 hash
```

But if I take not so big interval it decides to take simple amp retrieve for every data:

```
   select * from view -- not very simple logic
    where report_date between date'2016-06-01' and date'2016-12-31';

239) We do a single-AMP RETRIEVE step from
     tableName1 by way of the unique
     primary index "tableName1.gregor_dt =
     DATE '2016-08-08'" extracting row ids only with no residual
     conditions locking row for access into Spool 43 (group_amps),
     which is built locally on that AMP.  The size of Spool 43 is
     estimated with low confidence to be 221 rows.  The estimated time
     for this step is 0.00 seconds.
```

1) Second query fails because of spool problem. How to force teradata to use first plan?

**upd1**:

- There is  no double cast, just transforming from one date format to
  another.
- Both plans uses redistribution and I don't differences except pointed out places.
- TD overestimates number of rows, max 2-3 times ( I gave wrong info about that in comment)
- We have almost the same amount of information and statistics in DEV. However DEV server has 2 times lower amount of AMPS and nodes, in addition each amp tangibly less powerful. However TD in  dev start deciding to use first "good" plan for a shorter interval. How can we "fool" PROD server about that point?)

Comment: Most likely because your criteria `prd3_1_db_dmmonmis.t_greg_work_calendar.gregor_dt =
     DATE '2016-08-08` limits you to data on a single amp.  Those two explain steps you show there have absolutely nothing to do with each other.

Comment: @Andrew: This is a new feature in TD15.10, `BETWEEN` might be resolved to a list of unique values before optimization.

Comment: Strange, that the 2nd query runs into spool issues, probably Explain changes for later steps. You might try to confuse the optimizer by adding some unneccessary CASTs like `Cast(Cast(report_date  AS TIMESTAMP) AS DATE)`, but check the estimated number of rows if it's totally wrong.

Comment: @dnoeth: So the above query could potentially have a bunch of single amp retrieves for each distinct date in the `between`?  We're on 14, so I can't try that.

Comment: @Andrew: Yep, correct.

Comment: @dnoeth yep, we are using 15.10. According to viewpoint td underestimates 2-3 times on some steps , which is not so bad. And one more thing, bad plan goes to very high skew ~99, "good" plan to only 66%. Big tables doesn't have skew problems ((((

Comment: Does the double CAST work? Then compare both Explains to see the differences (probably a *redistributed* spool causing the skew).

Comment: @dnoeth According to this to 32nd slide - dropping statistics may safe the world?) https://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0ahUKEwjx_tL0jsnSAhVsOJoKHbTxC1QQFggsMAI&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.teradata.com.ru%2FAbout-Teradata%2FTeradata-User-Groups-(2014)%2FTUG-Presentation-Pages%2FTUG-Files%2F2014-Columbus-TUG-Teradata-15_0_Rob-Armstrong%2F&usg=AFQjCNEUza1deTCMKf-welEjcaAkNLmMqg&sig2=MavhSsdT84A_KoL3NMsFHA

Comment: I don't think that dropping stats will change the PI-access, of course it might change the expected number of rows, thus the following steps. Btw, when I try the double CAST on 15.10.02.06 the optimzer switched to Full Table Scan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it! To make it work just needed to trick TD two times)

The idea of query is to take table, then product join it to `Sys_Calendar` , and then apply row_number and some logic. Droping statistic may work, but TD may use sampling and cashing, that will eventually rune your work. This is why I applied `expand` + subquery in the view:

```
...
FROM   (    SEL cdate as cdate FROM (SELECT   DISTINCT      BEGIN      (tp) (NAMED cdate) 
    FROM           Sys_Calendar.CALDATES
    EXPAND       ON PERIOD (date '2014-01-01', current_date + 1) AS tp
    BY INTERVAL '1' DAY FOR PERIOD (date '2014-01-01',  current_date  + 1)
    ) A)  cldr
...
```

And after that I may apply and period I want by using `where` clause.

New plan faster by up to 15 times even the "good" plan!

Comment: Do you really need to create 73414*1165 (#days in calendar * #days between 2014-01-01 and today) rows first before applying the DISTINCT? What if you simplify it to `... FROM   (SELECT Begin (tp) (Named cdate) 
    FROM           Sys_Calendar.CALENDAR
    WHERE calendar_date = DATE '2014-01-01'
    EXPAND       ON PERIOD (calendar_date, Current_Date + 1) AS tp
    )  cldr ...`

Comment: @dnoeth Seems to be so.  For my solution - TD thinks that will by 55k rows, your - just 1.